# Redirect From one category to another

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, redirect

This is driving me insane :(

I need to redirect from one category to another existing category in Magento 1.9

I've tried to add a rewrite in magento's module but of course get the error Request Path for Specified Store already exists.

I've deleted it out and replaced it but then when it gets reindexed it get replaced by magentos behavior (yeah thanks magento)

Then if I add it to .htaccess file or Apache rewrite but its like magento is just ignoring it :(

What an awful behaviour this is in magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only thing I've found that works - but it's not the cleanest method. It goes in your `Custom Design > Custom Layout Update` area in the category you want to redirect FROM.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="SOME.BLOCK.NAME.HERE">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("https://www.WEBSITE.com/CUSTOM-REDIRECT");</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Nice one bro :)

It does look bounce around before it gets there but it does work :)

I know i need to put my url in the redirect 'location.replace' 
Am I supposed to put/replace anything for "SOME.BLOCK.NAME.HERE" ???

Thanks again man

Comment: To my understanding, the "name" area is optional and mostly used for your own classification. If you get in the habit of doing this alot, it would be smart to change the name to something that corresponds with the redirect. A more technical and long-winded approach could result in quicker load times/times redirects. Creating a new theme in your package with a new `template/page/html/head.phtml` would allow you to load the javascript directly in the head of just that page and should redirect a lot quicker.